# How to get when a site collections was created using the Get-PnPTenantSite command

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site-collection, pnp-powershell

How to get when a site collections was created using the Get-PnPTenantSite command?
For example when i do

```
Get-PnPTenantSite -Filter "Url -like '/mysitecollection'" -Detailed
```

The properties returned doesnt have created date.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The command  `Get-PnPTenantSite` would not return the site collection created date, you need to use `Get-PnPWeb -Includes Created` command to get Site Collection Created Date:

```
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Get the Root Web with "created" property
$Web = Get-PnPWeb -Includes Created
 
#Get Site Collection Created Date
Write-host "Site Collection Created on:"$Web.Created
```

Reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/09/sharepoint-online-get-site-collection-created-date.html

Update:

You could try this:

```
Get-PnPTenantSite $siteURL
(Get-PnPWeb -Includes Created).created
```

[image]

Comment: THanks for that Michael. But how can i combine Get-PnPTenantSite and Get-PnPWeb to return other properties plus created date?

Comment: Please check my update answer